# How to test for which emoji a user has reacted to a message?

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to make a system where a user can react to a message and it will reply with some text. The text will be different depending on which emoji they reacted with. I have researched reaction collectors, but I am still struggling to find an example of what I want to do.

This is the base code I am working with, which I got from Discord's guide to collections [here](https://discordjs.guide/popular-topics/collectors.html#basic-reaction-collector).

```js
message.react('');

const filter = (reaction, user) => {
  return reaction.emoji.name === '';
};

const collector = message.createReactionCollector(filter, { max: 100 });

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  message.channel.send('Collecting...')
});

collector.on('end', collected => {
  message.channel.send('Done');
});
```

This code works, however it will execute the code in `collector.on('collect'...` no matter which emoji is reacted with. I want to be able to execute different code, for example sending a different embed when a user reacts with different emojis. Thanks!

Comment: Hi! The link you posted displays some different code, which uses 'awaitReactions`... Also, please [edit] the question adding why this code doesn't work ;)

Comment: I have edited my question and corrected the mistakes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your collector filter will allow only  emojis to be collected, so you should remove that in order to make the bot behave differently when other reactions are added. You can use the `reaction` and `user` arguments to determine which action to do:

```js
// This will make it collect every reaction, without checking the emoji
const collector = message.createReactionCollector(() => true, { max: 100 })

collector.on('collect', (reaction, user) => {
  if (reaction.emoji.name == '') {
    // The user has reacted with the  emoji
  } else {
    // The user has reacted with a different emoji
  }
})

collector.on('end', collected => {
  // The bot has finished collecting reaction, because either the max number 
  // has been reached or the time has finished
})
```

Inside those `if/else` statements you can add whatever you want (send messages, embeds, ...)

Comment: I tried this out and, unfortunately, it didn't work? It worked once and then every other time I tried it, it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean by "didn't work"? Which part didn't work? Which action does it do in which cases, and how do you see that it's not working? Where did you put this code? What do you mean by "the first time": the first time you use it on every reaload or just the first time ever? I need some more details

Comment: Sorry for the vague comment. By didn't work, I mean the reactions worked properly, but the bot didn't respond when I did react to the message. It never does anything when I react. At the moment the code is in my tester bot, by itself. It is the only code in there. And my mistake, it didn't work the first time, I was using the code from Discord's guide, your code has never worked.

Comment: Sorry, but did you add somthing inside the `if/else` statement or you left it blank? Because if you just copied my code then it's normal that it doesn't do anything, since there are only comments in it: it was meant for you to add whatever you want to do (like sending a message with `message.channel.send()`) following the comments...

Comment: I did add some `message.channel.send()` inside the `if/else` statement but they never executed?

Comment: If you put `console.log(reaction)` in the line before the `if` statement, does anything get logged to the console?

Comment: It now seems to be working, however when I tried it earlier, I was not. I may have copied it wrong or deleted something by mistake. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: HAppy to hear that!